# How to add html select box in to laravel elequent form

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

i have a form like this

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'addjob')) }}   

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">SubCategories</label>

        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="subcategory" id="subcategory" >

            <option value=""></option>

        </select>
    </div>


    <p>titel :</p>

    <p>{{ Form::text('titel') }}</p>


    <p>prijs :</p>

    <p>{{ Form::text('prijs') }}</p>

    <p>beschrijving :</p>

    <p>{{ Form::text('beschrijving') }}</p>

    <p>{{ Form::submit('Submit') }}</p>



{{ Form::close() }}
```

as you can see the  section is plain html and not laravels elequents method like so
{{ Form::select('number', opt1,opt2,opt3}}

this is because i have the following script updating the value of this select box
the script that updates it is below:

```
 <script>
 $('#category').on('change',function(e){

    console.log(e);

     var cat_id = e.target.value; 

    $.get('ajax-subcat?cat_id=' + cat_id , function(data){


        //AJAX succes
        $('#subcategory').empty();
        $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj){

            $('#subcategory').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.titel+'</option>');

        });   
      });       
    });

 </script>
```

the field is only updated if i use the plain html version of the  instead of the Form::select

so now is my question. how do i add the value of the selectbox to my laravel form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel's form helpers generate "normal" HTML. You are probably having a problem because when you use `Form::select` you don't include the id. But your javascript code relies on the id attribute to select the element. Try this:

```
{{ Form::select('subcategory', array('' => ''), null, array('id' => 'subcategory', 'class' => 'form-control input-sm')) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the same html for your `<select>`:

```
{{ Form::select('subcategory', [''=>''], 0, ['id' => 'subcategory', 'class' => 'form-control input-sm']) }}
```

so you can use it and it will work the same.

Now, about your question - it doesn't matter if you output the form statically or build using javascript. Form values sent upon submit will be just the same, so no need for any changes.